# Implement Ball tree on pyspark for nearest position between two dataframes

Tags: pyspark, scikit-learn, user-defined-functions

I need to retrieve, to a dataframe presenting individual positions (`latitude`/`longitude`) of 6 million rows, the information about the nearest store (within 3km).

So I thought about the BallTree of scikit learn, building a `UDF`... Except that the information is presented in two different dataframes (and that the `broadcasting()` doesn't work in my working environment).

Do you have any tips to perform this join?

Find hereunder a replicable exemple and what I tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType, StringType, IntegerType
import numpy as np


individual_positions = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 52.03078, 0.29924), 
    (2, 55.27098, -4.35238), 
    (3, 56.40228, -4.62219), 
    (4, 55.32196, -1.90366), 
    (5, 52.73526, -0.25418)], 
    ['ind','lat','lon'])


df_store = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 52.03180, 0.30000), 
    (2, 57.22800, -3.22241), 
    (3, 55.27098, -4.32380), 
    (4, 58.41750, -3.67292), 
    (5, 57.44247, -5.18581)], 
    ['Store_ID','lat_store','lon_store'])

# deg radians
df_store = df_store.withColumn('lat_store_rad', f.radians(f.col('lat_store')))
df_store = df_store.withColumn('lon_store_rad', f.radians(f.col('lon_store')))
```

Define the function:

```
def get_nearest(src_points, candidates = df_store, k_neighbors=1):
        """Find nearest neighbors for all source points from a set of candidate points"""
        candidates_a = np.array(candidates.select('lat_store_rad', 'lon_store_rad').collect())
        src_points = np.array(src_points)
        tree = BallTree(candidates_a, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')
        distances, indices = tree.query(src_points, k=k_neighbors)
        distances = distances.transpose()
        indices = indices.transpose()
        closest = indices[0]
        closest_dist = distances[0]
        closest_store = candidates.filter(f.col('index')==int(closest[0]))
        earth_radius = 6371
        closest_store = closest_store.withColumn('distance', f.lit(closest_dist[0]) * f.lit(earth_radius) )
        # remove the closest if distance > 3km
        closest_store = closest_store.withColumn('Store_ID', f.when(f.col('distance')>3,'999999999').otherwise(f.col('Store_ID')))
        return (closest_store.select('Store_ID').collect())

# register udf
get_nearest_udf = f.udf(get_nearest, IntegerType())
```

Apply it:

```
individual_positions = individual_positions.withColumn('lat_rad', f.radians(f.col('lat')))
individual_positions = individual_positions.withColumn('lon_rad', f.radians(f.col('lon')))
# apply udf
individual_positions = individual_positions.withColumn('Store_ID', get_nearest_udf(src_points = individual_positions.select('lat_rad', 'lon_rad').collect()))
```

The function `get_nearest()` is working well (without spark / udf registration), but as we have two datasets it's not working in the spark/udf logic `get_nearest_udf()`.

The expected output would be the `individual_positions` added with the `Store_ID` information.

Many thanks for your advices

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am looking to do the exact same thing and am wondering if if it possible.